# How to group sub-list by having the same index?

Tags: python, rhino

It's a very difficult question to put to words. I am using Python in the modeling software Rhinoceros 3D. I have the following problem:

Take for example I have the following data.

```
l = [[1,2,3],[3,1.2,4],[1.000,2.0,3.0],[12,3,2],[1,5,3],[5,3,4],[1,6,2.0]]
```

I would like to group all the data that has the same z-value into one list:

so the result should be something like this:

```
l_2 = [[12,3,2],[1,6,2.0]]
l_3 = [[1,2,3], [1.000,2.0,3.0], [1,5,3]]
l_4 = [[3,1.2,4],[5,3,4]]
```

How do I accomplish this without using any plugin?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For example, you can use a dictionary and a `for` loop. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension with filtering is one way:

```
l_2 = [x for x in l if x[2] == 2]
l_3 = [x for x in l if x[2] == 3]
l_4 = [x for x in l if x[2] == 4]
```

Comment: Need to take care of the 3.0 as well!

Comment: @Kapil Not sure what you mean. 3.0 == 3 so it works fine.

Comment: Sorry! Didn't know that python did this!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `l` and append the sublist to a dict with the key of the `z` value:

```
d = {}
for x, y, z in l:
    d.setdefault(z, []).append([x, y, z])
```

`d` becomes:

```
{3: [[1, 2, 3], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1, 5, 3]], 4: [[3, 1.2, 4], [5, 3, 4]], 2: [[12, 3, 2], [1, 6, 2.0]]}
```